# executeUpdate - incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.sql.ResultSet JAVA

Tags: java, sql

Estoy intentando mediante un `JDialog` de un formulario alta vehículo hacer una inserción en una tabla de la base de datos. Al pulsar el boton "`Enviar/OK/Insertar`" para añadirlo en la base de datos me da el siguiente error:

```
Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.sql.ResultSet
```

Os dejo la función entera para que veáis como en `rs=stm.executeUpdate(insertar_vehiculo);` es donde está el fallo.

```
public static void alta_vehiculo(Vehiculo v){
        String bd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        String insertar_vehiculo = "";
        try{
            //Consulta para insertar un nuevo vehículo en la base de datos.
            stm = c.createStatement();
            //Comprobamos si v es una instancia de Vehiculo_Alquiler...
            if(v instanceof Vehiculo_Alquiler){
                insertar_vehiculo = "INSERT INTO vehiculos "
                        + "(bastidor, color, matricula, marca, modelo, potencia, consumo, "
                        + "fecha_fabricacion, descripcion) "
                        + "VALUES "
                        + "('"+v.getBastidor()+"', '"+v.getColor()+"', '"+v.getMatricula()+"', "+v.getMarca()+","
                        + "'"+v.getModelo()+"', "+v.getPotencia()+", "+v.getConsumo()+", "
                        + "'"+v.getFecha_fabricacion()+"', '"+v.getDescripcion()+"');";
                rs = stm.executeUpdate(insertar_vehiculo);

                String insertar_vehiculo_alquiler = "INSERT INTO vehiculos_alquiler "
                        + "(bastidor, precio_alquiler, fecha_v_alquiler, disponible) "
                        + "VALUES "
                        + "('"+v.getBastidor()+"', "+((Vehiculo_Alquiler)v).getPrecio_alquiler()+", "
                        + "'"+((Vehiculo_Alquiler)v).getFecha_v_alquiler()+", "+((Vehiculo_Alquiler)v).isDisponible()+"');";
                rs = stm.executeUpdate(insertar_vehiculo_alquiler);
                System.out.println("Vehículo insertado correctamente en vehiculo y vehiculo_alquiler.");
            }else{
                //Al no ser una instancia de Vehiculo_Alquiler, lo será de Vehiculo_Compra.
                insertar_vehiculo = "INSERT INTO vehiculos "
                        + "(bastidor, color, matricula, marca, modelo, potencia, consumo, "
                        + "fecha_fabricacion, descripcion) "
                        + "VALUES "
                        + "('"+v.getBastidor()+"', '"+v.getColor()+"', '"+v.getMatricula()+"', "+v.getMarca()+","
                        + "'"+v.getModelo()+"', "+v.getPotencia()+", "+v.getConsumo()+", "
                        + "'"+v.getFecha_fabricacion()+"', '"+v.getDescripcion()+"');";
                rs = stm.executeUpdate(insertar_vehiculo);
                String insertar_vehiculo_compra = "INSERT INTO vehiculos_compra "
                        + "(bastidor, precio_venta, fecha_v_compra) "
                        + "VALUES "
                        + "('"+v.getBastidor()+"', "+((Vehiculo_Compra)v).getPrecio_venta()+"', "+((Vehiculo_Compra)v).getFecha_v_compra()+"');";
                rs = stm.executeUpdate(insertar_vehiculo_compra);
                System.out.println("Vehículo insertado correctamente en vehiculo y vehiculo_compra.");
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de datos devuelve el método `Statement.executeUpdate`? ¿Qué tipo de datos tiene `rs`?

Comment: executeQuery() --- This is used generally for reading the content of the database. The output will be in the form of ResultSet. Generally SELECT statement is used. 

executeUpdate() --- This is generally used for altering the databases. Generally DROP TABLE or DATABASE, INSERT into TABLE, UPDATE TABLE, DELETE from TABLE statements will be used in this. The output will be in the form of int. This int value denotes the number of rows affected by the query.

Comment: La diferencia es que no puedo usar executeQuery debido a que solo es para SELECT, no para modificar o añadir en tablas.

Comment: `executeUpdate()` te devuelve un valor entero y no de tipo `resultset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

executeUpdate no te devuelve un ResultSet, te devuelve el número de rows afectadas por la query ejecutada.

Aqui tienes más info:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

Comment: Probaré con execute(), es la última opción que me queda. Lo acabo de probar y en execute() es el mismo error en vez de "int" (executeUpdate) me sale "boolean".

Comment: ¿alguna idea como solución para insertar esa consulta e la bbdd?

Comment: Solo guarda el retorno en un int y no en un resultSet, te devolverá el numero de filas que inserto.

Comment: Lo que no sé es como arreglarlo para que me funcione la consulta. Si me devuelve un entero... y espero un resultSet...

Comment: Si devuelve un entero, deberías esperar un entero o no esperar nada, simplemente lanzas el insert y  compruebas en la BBDD que se inserto correctamente.

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo comprobarlo si rs devuelve un int y espera un ResultSet? Eso es lo que me despista.

Comment: int resultado;
resultado = stm.executeUpdate(insertar_vehiculo); en vez de: 
ResultSet rs;
rs = stm.executeUpdate(insertar_vehiculo); 
El ResultSet no es necesario para nada al insertar datos.

Comment: Solucionado, ahora me da el siguiente error... dic 28, 2016 7:14:15 PM interfaz.Alta_vehiculo button_OKActionPerformed
GRAVE: null
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2005-05-05"